# I'm thinking of moving my site to Squarespace as I have little time to manage my site

Tags: seo, web-hosting, traffic

I'm thinking of moving my site to Squarespace, I have around 40 pages with videos, screenshots and web forms etc, my blog is wordpress and I want to move everything on to Squarespace. My worry is that I'll suffer some SEO loss, has anyone used Squarespace or moved any clients over and was there any drop in traffic/SEO issues?

I have very little time on my hands for web design and would like to keep adding content to my site so it does seem ideal. I make my living from my site so I really don't want to make a mess of it.

Any advice from those that are using Squarespace would be very welcome.

Thanks Steve

Comment: PS My site has a full domain www.mysite.com and I will be taking advantage of Squarespace ability to ue my existing URL.

Comment: What exactly do you hope Squarespace will save you time with? Once you have a CMS set up, there should be very little managing aside from content updates. SEO/SEM, etc. might also be needed, but that's not something that Squarespace would be able to help you with.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Squarespace lets you use your own domain name so if your URLs will remain unchanged you will be fine. But if that is not the case, and some or all of your URLs will be changing, you will need to be able to do 301 redirects to redirect the old URLs to the new URLs. If they allow you to do this the SEO impact will be temporary and minimal (although you should contact any sites linking to you and ask them top update their links).

If you cannot do 301 redirect then you will have SEO issues as any links to pages that no longer exist will essentially become useless. You will also have to wait for the search engines to re-index your site, find the new pages, and then add them to their indices. This will almost certainly result is less traffic (assuming you are getting traffic from the search engines). It's almost like starting from scratch, SEO wise.

If your site currently gets good search engine rankings and good traffic as a result of it, this move may be more harmful then beneficial if your site structure is going to change a lot. If your site gets little to no traffic from search and/or has poor rankings this move can help as you will be able to better focus on your content which is what you need to get good rankings.

Comment: Thanks John, why would the change in site structure make a difference? I do plan on keeping the pages in the same place so all URLs remain valid. E.g. www.mysite.com/products/cups.html would need to remain.

Comment: If your site structure changes then your URLs will all be different. Search engines rank pages, not websites, so if your pages' URLs change they will be seen as new pages by the search engines. If your URLs will not be changing then you have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Upkeep is easy but if you are using the Community feature of Squarespace you can not easily do email campaigns to your groups with out exporting (every time) to a third party email list manager. I am considering moving off SQ SP because of this.